# Problem with asymptote directory

Tags: asymptote, directory

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, UTF8, scheme = plain]{ctexrep}
\usepackage{amsmath,tasks}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\begin{asydef}
import olympiad;
import cse5;
import graph;
size(6cm);
\end{asydef}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% \renewcommand\asydir{}   %%%% files used to be generated just under the same directory without any problem
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Square $ ABCD $ has side length $10$.
Point $E$ is on $\overline{BC}$, and the area of $ \triangle ABE $
is $40$.
What is $ BE $?
\begin{center}
\begin{asy}
pair A,B,C,D,E;
A=(0,0);
B=(0,50);
C=(50,50);
D=(50,0);
E = (30,50);
draw(A--B);
draw(B--E);
draw(E--C);
draw(C--D);
draw(D--A);
draw(A--E);
dot(A);
dot(B);
dot(C);
dot(D);
dot(E);
label("A",A,SW);
label("B",B,NW);
label("C",C,NE);
label("D",D,SE);
label("E",E,N);
\end{asy}
\end{center}
\begin{tasks}(5)
\task 4
\task 5
\task 6
\task 7
\task 8
\end{tasks}
\end{document}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Some asy packages are from here

```
https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Asymptote:_Macros_and_Packages
```

When run with (in Notepad++ from Nppexec)

```
cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
pdflatex $(NAME_PART).tex
asy.exe -v *.asy
```

I got the following error:

```
Processing cse5
failed to create directory /.asy.
Processing olympiad
failed to create directory /.asy.
Processing tmppp-1
    pic.addBox(position,position,min(f),max(f));
              ^
```

The pdf part should all be fine. But I seem to have some problems with the directory?
And it seemed to be some path under linux format? Which I am using windows.
It used to work about a year ago, but only occurred now.

My environment is

```
Windows 10
Miktex (latest)
```